# Magento 2 Add to cart Error

Tags: magento2, addtocart

When I add a product to cart , It is not added it throws an error
        **"No Such entity with customerId ="**
  This Error also shown in My Account page when try to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are getting **No Such entity with customerId** e when  ***magento is `not able to load a customer` by it Customer repository class***.

**May be  few reasons this issue is occurring:**

1. **May be  Cart object has wrong  customer id**,so you need to check at
   **database at quote table**.
2. May be **Custom code and custom has changes the behavior of Customer
   model class and it repository classes,You need to check that  need
   to fixed it**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have create any observer for cart for ex:- sales_quote_add_item then disable that and check.
I have also facing same issue when click on reorder then i got same error.
"No Such entity with customerId ="